# Placeholder in JTextField With the right direction

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I use the following code to create a placeholder in JTextField, but my problem is Placeholder text direction always on the left

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics pG) {
    super.paintComponent(pG);

    if (placeholder.length() == 0 || getText().length() > 0) {
        return;
    }

    final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) pG;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(new Color(phColor.getRed(),phColor.getGreen(),phColor.getBlue(),140));


   g.drawString(placeholder, getMargin().right,(getSize().height)/2 + getFont().getSize()/2 );
}
```

How can I create a placeholder on JTextField with the text direction to the right?

Here is an image of my problem

[image]

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Thank you so much. But I unsuccessfully tried to get the right edge of the JTextField .
Although use the getMargin.right () or getInsets().right methods And those methods redirect to the text field component

Answer (score 0):

Use the FontMetrics class:

```
FontMetrics fM = g.getFontMetrics(/*The font that you're using*/);

g.drawString(/* Your Text */, rightEdge - fM.stringWidth(/* Your Text */), y);
```

You get the right edge by adding the x-position to the width of your JTextField.
Don't you already have a method for this: "getMargin.right()"? Or is this for something else?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but how can I get to the right edge of the component?

Comment: any other ideas?